# How to find out how many rows match a rule?

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to find out how many rows in a table of my database meet a certain rule, specifically that "category" matches another variable and "published" is today or earlier. Then I want to simply echo that number.

I have no idea how to go about doing this, though.

I thought I could use count() but I'm not sure how to call just a single column and put the results of each row in an array.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, for starters, do you know how to connect to your db and execute a query against it?

Comment: show your database structure or condition or php statements

Answer (score 0):

Do this using SQL:

Try this in your database (your columns/tables may be different):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM blog_posts WHERE category = 'hot_stuff' and published <= NOW();
```

Then to execute this in PHP, depending on your framework and connection to the database:

```
    $myCategory = 'hot_stuff';
    $myTable = 'blog_posts';

    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM {$myTable} WHERE category = '{$myCategory}' and published <= NOW();";

    $rowCount = $db->query($sql);
    echo $rowCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Connect to your database.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

   ```
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
   ```
2. [Create a prepared statement.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) This is essential because you need to pass a value for category from your application to the query. It is not necessary to pass a value for the current date because the database can provide that for you. The `?` is a placeholder where the parameter you pass will be bound.

   ```
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table 
                      WHERE category = ? AND published  <= CURDATE()");
   ```

   Do not concatenate the parameter into your SQL string (like `WHERE category = '$category'`) because this will create an [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) vulnerability.
3. [Execute the prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) using your specified value for category.

   ```
   $stmt->execute([$category]);   // assuming you have already defined $category
   ```
4. Use [`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to return a single value, the count of rows that matched your criteria.

   ```
   echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
   ```